# Gitlab SAST/DAST configuration for memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, gitlab, sast

I have a repository that contains C and CPP Android NDK code that I would like to do SCA analysis on to determine whether there are memory leaks in the modules. I have ran HWASAN and ASAN scans on the code, but I am limited to the amount that I can test since the code base is big, and not all of it can be tested without writing extensive test code that imports those libraries for usage. I am wondering if SAST/DAST can be set up to allow me to catch memory leaks much better, and if not, what would be the best SCA tool (hopefully free) that can help me resolve this easiest?